# LWC of Activity Timeline Component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, activityhistory

in my business area, we have a need to replicate the standard activity timeline component (on the contact record page) but make it custom because we want to do things like having more flexibility around showing cross object fields (appending case subject name in places it doesn't show , adding case notes , etc.

I wanted to start with replicating the standard activity timeline component the closest I can (the filters, the timeline of tasks, emails, events, etc. with their identifiers, etc. ) This sounds like a complex task. I know I will need apex for the business logic (returning the activity) and would like to do a LWC route for the front-end portion.  Do you know of any examples or starting points that I could look to help me get close to that?

thanks!

Comment: I'm attempting a similar task. Did you end up doing it? What did you do with the Send Email, Create Task, etc. quick actions built into the standard Activities component?

Answer (score 1):

There are various example available which you can refer to start with:-

1. https://github.com/anandbn/timeline-lwc
2. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G0yN3UAJ
3. https://awesomeopensource.com/project/deejay-hub/timeline-lwc
4. https://kshitijlawate.com/salesforce-record-history-in-timeline-view-using-a-custom-lightning-web-component/
5. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/activity-timeline/

Answer (score 0):

I built TimelinePlus to add filters to a custom timeline component, its pretty straightforward to build the basics but when you get deeper into it pulling all the records from different objects together and the functionality which goes with it starts to get tricky.

I could probably extend it with some of the features you need if it would help, give me a shout on here or through the AppExchange listing if you want to talk through options:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000Ptw9dEAB